# JQuery Week Calendar Setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an enormous amount of difficulty (for no apparent reason) getting the jquery week calendar to show up at all.

I link to these files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/transporter/jquery-weekcalendar-1.2.2/jquery.weekcalendar.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/transporter/jquery-weekcalendar-1.2.2/jquery.weekcalendar.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript src='/transporter/jquery-weekcalendar-1.2.2/jquery.weekcalendar.js.min.js"></script>
```

And I init my calendar like this:

```
$( "#eventscalendar" ).weekCalendar({
                      timeslotsPerHour : 4,
                      allowCalEventOverlap : true,
                      overlapEventsSeparate: true,
                      firstDayOfWeek : 1,
                      businessHours :{start: 8, end: 18, limitDisplay: true },
                      daysToShow : 7,
                      height : 300});
```

and here's my DIV:

```
<div 
    id="eventscalendar" 
    class="span11">

</div>
```

The error I'm seeing is this:

```
Uncaught type error: [object Object] has no method 'weekCalendar'
```

I'm using Bootstrap. The problem has got to be missing CSS or JS references but the code I'm finding online in demos is not working for me at all.

Does JQuery Week Calendar not like Bootstrap? What could I possibly be missing here?

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect **closing tags**

And looks like you are **not loading jQuery in the first place**

```
<script type="text/javascript 'src='/transporter/jquery-weekcalendar-1.2.2/jquery.weekcalendar.js.min.js"
                             ^--------------
```

supposed to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/transporter/jquery-weekcalendar-1.2.2/jquery.weekcalendar.js.min.js"
```

And need to make sure `jquery` is included before you use the `jquery claender plugin`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/transporter/jquery-weekcalendar-1.2.2/jquery.weekcalendar.css">

// jQuery shold be loaded before you include your weekcalender plugin 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/transporter/jquery-weekcalendar-1.2.2/jquery.weekcalendar.js.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure you only include either the `minified` or the `development` version. But not both the javascript files.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a quick and correct response. My JavaScript is very bad (just came over from Flex) so I didn't realize that placement mattered. Thank you very much!

Comment: @fumeng .. Glad to have helped :)